Efficient Path to Travel the object through point with Timeline in Unreal Engine
I'm currently working on a project in Unreal Engine 5.2 where I need to dynamically adjust timeline durations in Blueprint based on varying distances between path points to ensure smooth and efficient movement. Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on calculating and setting movement speed based on these distances.
I have path points stored in an array of vectors, and I've noticed that my current implementation results in the same travel time between points, regardless of whether they are very close or far apart. How can I effectively adjust movement speed to optimize travel from the starting point to the last point in my path array?
When I pull the item, i have got the path of the points in array.
When i try to pull the Pull Item is called at first.

and then it called Initialize path movement to get the total distance.

and try to move through the point.

But this is not working correctly,  the alpha is 0.0000 here and it doesn't move, what i am doing wrong here? I want to move the object.
